# Taking unique variables from one column and adding up the totals in another - Python

Tags: python

I need some assistance with my code in python that I tried to write. My objective is to count the authors who have written a unique number of books in a given time frame. The data has multiple duplicate books that need to be removed.

This is an example of what it looks like now:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LXKlF.png

This is how I would like the outcome to be:
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YSf5M.png

Code:

```
# top Authors with most best sellers
df_top_Authors = raw_df.sort_values('Name',ascending = False).head(100)
 
df_top_Authors.groupby(['Author']).size().reset_index().rename(columns={0:'nb_best_sellers'}).sort_values('nb_best_sellers',ascending = False)
```

Comment: Please post a minimal working example.

Comment: Apologies, my formatting was off

Comment: Even with the formatting, that's not an [mre]. [Please do not upload images of code/errors/data when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Make sure the code *actually works* to reproduce the problem. Don't expect people to transcribe data from an image or to fill in the blanks of your code – that is time and motivation wasted that *won't* go towards answering your question.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem is only that duplicates are counted?
In such case you can remove duplicates before grouping:

```
df_top_Authors.drop_duplicates().groupby(['Author'])\
.size().reset_index().rename(columns={0:'nb_best_sellers'})\
.sort_values('nb_best_sellers',ascending = False)
```

Comment: I'd like to drop the duplicates from the book names. Then count how many times an author wrote a book in the dataset. The code you wrote still takes into account the duplicates

Comment: I have tested it and duplicates aren't taken into account. E.g for 
`df = pd.DataFrame({"Name": ["A", "A", "C", "D", "E"], "Author": ["King", "King", "Seus", "Backman", "Seus"]})` dataframe it works well